# Camera calibration sequence with ground truth data

Tags: slam, stereo-vision, visual-odometry, monocular

I'm looking for a SLAM dataset (monocular or stereo) specifically with a checkerboard, meaning the camera always has a checkerboard in frame.

Most popular datasets provide calibration sequences, however said calibration sequences do not contain ground truth data and can only be used to calibrate the camera.

Is there any datasets out there that provides its calibration sequence with ground truth data available?